# mysqli_fetch_assoc in a Function

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, fetch

I wanted to have a function that will fetch using mysqli_fetch_assoc() it is something like this:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "primary");
function fetchAssoc($query){
    global $con;
    $queryexec = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $return = array();
    while($stuff = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryexec)){
        $return[] = $stuff;
    }
    return $return;
}
$yup = fetchAssoc("SELECT * FROM posts");
while($thing = $yup){
    echo $thing, "<br />";
}
?>
```

But for some reason I get this result:
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\Experiments\index.php on line 20
Array

Line 20 is `echo $thing, "<br />";`

Comment: replace , by . and replace echo var_dump().See any luck??

Comment: `$yup` is an array and `$thing` is an array, too. $yup represents each row and $thing is each field of your db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this program.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "primary");
function fetchAssoc($query){
    global $con;
    $queryexec = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $return = array();
    while($stuff = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryexec)){
        $return[] .= $stuff['name'];  //Enter your column name in place of name from your posts table.
    }
    return $return;
}
$yup = fetchAssoc("SELECT * FROM posts");

foreach($yup as $thing){
    echo $thing . "<br />";
}
?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$yup = fetchAssoc("SELECT * FROM posts");
while($thing = $yup){
    echo $thing, "<br />";
}
```

`$yup` is an **associative array**, and in your while loop you're assigning to `$thing` - which now is an array too

You should do something like

```
foreach($yup as $y){

  // here $y is an array in the form of 
  // array( ['column_name'] => 'value', '[other_col]' => 'value')
  // so you could do 
  echo $y['column'], $y['other_col'],'<br />';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`fetch_assoc` returns an array of items, to print them all out at once (to see what is there) you could do this:

`print_r($thing);`

or if you want to print them out individually something like this:

```
foreach($thing as $t){
  echo $t . '<br />';
}
```

Also, the while loop is going to run forever though because it is essentially this:

```
while(true){
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "primary");
function fetchAssoc($query){
global $con;
$queryexec = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$return = array();
while($stuff = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryexec)){
    $return[] = $stuff;
}
return $return;
}
$yup = fetchAssoc("SELECT * FROM posts");
foreach($yup AS $thing){
 // $thing is an associative array so use keys to access data from it like
  echo $thing['ID'], "<br />";
}
?>
```

Comment: several of your recent edits have been rejected because they are very minor.  Look for items that need real change.

Answer (score 0):

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "primary");
function fetchAssoc($query){
    global $con;
    $queryexec = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $return = array();
    while($stuff = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryexec)){
        $return[] = $stuff;
    }
    return $return;
}
$yup = fetchAssoc("SELECT * FROM posts");
foreach($yup as $thing){
    foreach($thing as $element){
        echo $element."<br/>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code is perfect. But just one mistake. Here $thing is an array so you can't echo it.
Try this:

```
while($thing = $yup){
   print_r ($thing);
   echo  "<br />";
}
```